# How to use mysql with conda?

Tags: mysql, conda, ubuntu-20.04

I am learning sql and for that I needed to download MySQL on my Ubunutu 20.04. I have some issues with my kernels and therefore can't use `sudo`. Therefore I created a virtualenv using conda and downloaded MySQL using `conda install -c anaconda mysql`. Now I need to do setup like setting password for the MySQL and create a database in which I can make tables and learn how to write queries. Can anyone please suggest a way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use `mysql-client` in a restricted environment where don't have root access for installing packages; you can simply grab the static binary of `mysql` (around 4MB) and use it directly from terminal of restricted machine.